# How to prevent database dump?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, copy, dump

i create my first Android app that use local SQLite database for showing contents.
As you know any user can dump database from phone and see its structure and data.
Does exist any way to prevent database dump from Android phones?
I avoid that anynone can have a look at database data (and then copy it) using any SQLite explorer.

Thank you.

Comment: SQLite accept password file and you must search for encryption in SQLite/Android here.

Comment: Then could any expert user disassemble apk and the obtain password file?

Comment: the password is setted in SQLite connection string

Answer (score 0):

Using password in the connection string

```
Data Source=filename;Version=3;Password=myPassword;
```

Source: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite

or encrypting (Search here for SO answers)

Comment: Android does not use a connection string. (And the built-in SQLite does not support encryption.)